# Computer turns off randomly, turns back on only after wiggling all the power cables

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, connection

sometimes my computer turns off for absolutely no reason.

- Sometimes it just shuts off, randomly, and wont turn on
- Sometimes, it'll turn back on, then immediately shut off before it can boot

If I wiggle the cables it starts working again.

I'm thinking its either a problem with my PSU (Corsair A860I) or a problem with the power connection on my case (Thermaltake level 10 GT). I hope it isn't a problem with the motherboard, but it might be(i dont know the specific MB model but it's a Gigabyte Ultra Durable with an Am3+ socket).

Comment: The power connection on your case is the power connection to the PSU, so either way, it's the PSU.  The obvious solution is to stop jiggling the power cable.

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate why you are jiggling the power cable, and include in the PSU description if the cables are modular or not.  If there is a good reason for jiggling (I can't think of one), a workaround may be discovered.  The case should be closed 99% of the time, so the power cables shouldn't be getting jiggled.  That being said, casual movement should not unseat the power cable either at the PSU port or at the motherboard port, so consider replacing the

Answer (score 0):

Check the cable and all connectors for loose seating, slightly bent pins or anything else.

If you can't see anything, try a new cable.